# Unable to get values in accordance with items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to get the item and it's value in a dictionary. When I run my script, it does fetch that in the wrong way, I meant not in that way I wish to have.

The result I'm having now is like:

```
{'4194813.75690': 'foo', '4194813.75691': 'foo'}
```

But, I wish to have:

```
{'4194813.75690': 'foo', '4194813.75691': 'bar'}
```

In the `name` attribute this portion `4194813` is always stable but this `.75691` portion changes dynamically so I could not use any suitable flag in `.startswith()` other than what i've tried below.

This is the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.electricityregistry.co.nz/bin_public/jadehttp.dll?MariaWebR"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

formdata = {}

for items in soup.select("[name='JadeForm'] input"):
    if items.get("name").startswith('4194813'):
        item = items.get("name")
        val = "foo"  #how to change it to "bar" in the second iteration
        formdata[item] = val

print(formdata)
```

Comment: Where are foo and bar coming from?

Comment: They do not exist in that site. I want to use them cause one will be used as `username` (the foo) and the other will be as `password` (the bar). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So do you just want every iteration to alternate between foo and bar? Im not entirely sure I understand

Comment: They only appear twice so there should not be any confusion.

Comment: You could create a list `val = ["foo","bar"]` and have another variable i set to 0. When the if statement happens once, set `formdata[item] = val[i]`. Then` i +=1` then the next loop, it will put the second item, bar, into the formdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. You have the right idea using a variable; you just need to figure out when to change it. An easy way is to assign "foo" to `val` before entering your loop, use it to assign your dictionary value, then change `val` to "bar" after it's been used.

```
val = "foo"
for items in soup.select("[name='JadeForm'] input"):
    if items.get("name").startswith('4194813'):
        item = items.get("name")
        formdata[item] = val
        val = "bar"
```

Another way is to put the values into a list, make an iterator over the list, then use `next()` to get the next value from the iterator. This is a more general approach that can be used with any number of items, not just two.

```
val = iter(["foo", "bar"])
for items in soup.select("[name='JadeForm'] input"):
    if items.get("name").startswith('4194813'):
        item = items.get("name")
        formdata[item] = next(val)
```

Comment: What a fix @kindall!! Thanks a trillion.

Comment: The second one is more robust. You made my day.